# Open file limit is not Changing in Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, 22.04, filesystem, syslinux, ulimit

I need to increase the open file limit size in my system,

I have made changes in the following files,

```
file:-/etc/security/limits.conf
```

changes:-

```
* soft     nproc          990000
* hard     nproc          990000
* soft     nofile         990000
* hard     nofile         990000
root soft     nproc          990000
root hard     nproc          990000
root soft     nofile         990000
root hard     nofile         990000
ubuntu soft     nproc          990000
ubuntu hard     nproc          990000
ubuntu soft     nofile         990000
ubuntu hard     nofile         990000
```

file:-`/etc/pam.d/common-session`

change:- `session required pam_limits.so`

file:-`/etc/sysctl.conf`

change:-

```
fs.file-max = 2097152
vm.swappiness=1
```

file:- `/etc/systemd/system.conf`
change:- `DefaultLimitNOFILE=999990`

then I applied the changes using the `sudo sysctl -p` command, But it was showing open files size 1024,

open file limit is not changed,

Please help me, to increase the file limit size.

Operating system:- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I want to increase the file limit size to 990000.